# AngularJS unit test Directive's attribute value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, karma-jasmine

I have a directive that looks like this:

```
<foo bar="5"></foo>
```

where bar is an attribute and **not** defined in the scope property of the DDO.  How can I write a unit test to assert that the value of bar is 5?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work for you:

```
var element = $compile("<foo bar="5"></foo>")($rootScope);
$rootScope.$digest();
var ctrl = element.find('foo').controller('fooController');

expect(ctrl.bar).toBe("5");
```